# How to dynamically set og:image meta tag with php in joomla?

Tags: php, html, facebook, joomla, meta-tags

I'm trying to dynamically set the og:image meta tag for a joomla 1.5 website with a logic on a part of the url.

This is the code:

```
<?php 
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 
if (strpos($actual_link,'basket') !== false) { 
?>

<meta property="og:image" content="http://astel-teglio.it/site/images/Basketball.png" />

<?php
}else{
?>

<meta property="og:image" content="http://astel-teglio.it/site/images/LOGO.jpg" />

<?php
}
?>
```

The logic is very simple, if the url contains basket I want to use the image Basketball.png, else LOGO.jpg.

If I watch the source code in the browser I see the right attribute but when a paste the link on facebook I always see the Logo image (else case).

There are the two sample pages:

- [link with basket in the url (then case)](http://astel-teglio.it/site/it/minibasket/stagione-20132014/scoiattoli/317--morbegno--molino-tudori-teglio-12-12.html)
- [link  without basket in the url (else case)](http://astel-teglio.it/site/it/manifestazioni/altre-manifestazioni/318-pronti-per-il-natale-2013.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is caused by the [SEF URLs](http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs) that change my url from:

```
http://astel-teglio.it/site/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=317
```

to:

```
http://astel-teglio.it/site/it/minibasket/stagione-20132014/scoiattoli/317--morbegno--molino-tudori-teglio-12-12.html
```

but when [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://astel-teglio.it/site/it/minibasket/stagione-20132014/scoiattoli/317--morbegno--molino-tudori-teglio-12) loads the meta tags it load the original url that hasn't basket in the url string and so it loads the standard image.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla you can dynamically set og:attributes or meta tags like below.

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
if($shareTitle != '')
    $doc->addCustomTag( '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$shareTitle.'" />'  );
if($shareDesc != '')
    $doc->addCustomTag( '<meta property="og:description" content="'.$shareDesc.'" />' );
if($shareImg != '')
    $doc->addCustomTag( '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$shareImg.'" />' );
```

You can also check [How to set meta data of a page in joomla](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-set-meta-data-of-a-page-in-joomla).

Also facebook have cache issue, you can debug [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you, but I think that $shareImg is an image of the joomla article but I want to always set the same image for an entire section (i.e. a basketball foto for section "basket", a soccer photo for section "calcio")

Comment: @MigioB its not Joomla's article image those are dummy var you can just set anything you want for every articles.